# how to store deleted records in mysql database using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

`I want to store deleted records in Mysql database using Codeigniter`

In Simple word when  delete a record in database but i want the deleted record save  in other table in my  database
I have add_news  table in mysql database in this table have 6 columns id,title,news,image,publish_date,status

Comment: I think the easyest way is to overload this function/method which is used to delete records and add backup functionality to it.

Comment: if you want deleted column not to be deleted physically, Why don't you have another column "deleted" and rather it otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i have solution of this question

```
function delete_news($id)
    {

        $query = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO deleted_news (news_id,title,image,news,type,user_id,post_of_day,publish_date) SELECT id,title, image,news,type,user_id,post_of_day,publish_date FROM add_news WHERE id = $id");


        $query = $this->db->query("Delete from add_news where id = $id");


        //$this->db->last_query(); exit;
        //print_r($this->db->last_query());
        ///die;
        if($query)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$this->load->database();
$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=$id');
$query=$this->db->get();
foreach ($query->result as $row){
        $columnname1 = $row->columnname1
        $columnname2 = $row->columnname2
        $columnname3 = $row->columnname3
        $columnname4 = $row->columnname4
        $columnname5 = $row->columnname5
        $columnname6 = $row->columnname6
        $array = array($columnname1,$columnname2,$columnname3,$columnname4,$columnname5,$columnname6);
        $this->load->model('your insert to database model');
        $this->insert_model_name->model_function($array);

        $this->load->model('your delete from database model');
        $this->delete_model_name->model_function($id);

}
?>
```

I'm just going to assume you know how to do the models for insert and delete. This code also assumes you're using ID to select your column to delete. But since you didn't provide us with any code to take a look at, i'm guessing it was the logic you were having trouble with.

Comment: Good overall solution, to limit read and writes I'd probably flag the the rows as deleted and move them in bulk once a day when server activity is low instead of doin it constantly, but that depends on the usecase.